# Socket thread clients cant chat with each other

Tags: java, sockets

I wanted to program an chat server with sockets. I wanted , that at least two but theoretically even more can connect and chat in one big "room".
I have 2 classes for this, one server and one client class. But somehow they can only chat with themself.

**The Server:**

```
package Threads.tcp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ChatServer {

private static int PORT = 10023;

public static List<Socket> verbindungen = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Server auf Port 10023 horchen lassen
    try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
        System.out.println("Echo-Server bereit am Port " + PORT);

        while (true) {
            // Auf ankommende Verbindung warten, accept() blockiert so  
lange
            Socket verbindung = server.accept();
            verbindungen.add(verbindung);
            Thread t = new Thread(new Client(verbindung));
            threads.add(t);
            t.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

**The Client:**

```
package Threads.tcp;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Client implements Runnable {

protected List<String> clientList = new ArrayList();

protected int ID;

protected Socket verbindung;

public Client( Socket verbindung) throws IOException {
    this.verbindung = verbindung;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    //       Client-Thread (z.B. EchoHandler.java) ausgelagert werden.
    Writer w = null;
    try {
        w = new OutputStreamWriter(verbindung.getOutputStream(), 
Charset.forName("utf-8"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(w);

    Reader r = null;
    try {
        r = new InputStreamReader(verbindung.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);

    try {

        System.out.println("Verbindung angenommen von " + 
verbindung.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        w.write("Hallo dies ist der Chat Server der 3ci" + "\r\n");
        w.flush();
        w.write("Bitte /quit zum beenden):\r\n");
        w.flush();
        w.write("Welchen Spitznamen moechtest du haben: ");
        w.flush();

        BufferedReader name = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(verbindung.getInputStream()));
        String clientName;
        do {
            clientName = name.readLine();
            if (clientList.contains(clientName)) {
                w.write("Der Spitzname ist schon vergeben waehle einen
 anderen: ");
                w.flush();
            }
        } while (clientList.contains(clientName));

        // Add name to list
        clientList.add(clientName);
        ID = clientList.size() - 1;

        w.write(clientList.get(ID) + " hat den Raum betreten." + "\r\n");
        w.flush();

        while (true) {
            // Eingabeaufforderung senden und Zeile einlesen
            bw.write(clientList.get(ID) + ">");
            bw.flush();

            String zeile = br.readLine();
            if (zeile.equals("/quit")) {
                clientList.remove(ID);
                break;
            }

            if (zeile.trim().isEmpty()) {
                bw.write("\r\n");
                bw.flush();
            } else {
                zeile += "\r\n";
                bw.write(zeile);

            }

        }

        System.out.println("Verbindung beendet mit " + 
verbindung.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        verbindung.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I connected my clients with PUTTY and I used RAW , because I am programming on windows.

I hope you guys can help.
Regards Lukas.

Comment: What do you mean with "connected with PUTTY and RAW"? Putty is just an SSH/Telnet Client, I don't understand how can you start a Java application with that? Also I don't see how you start a client to server connection with your code.

Comment: After starting the server I am opening PUTTY then I choose ( Host Name "localhost" , Port "10023" , Connection type "Raw") and after that I am opening the connection and it works. But I cant "talk/write" to more than one client.

Comment: Ah ok you mean you use putty as your client, now I understand. I thought you use your Java Client class for that as well, that confused  me a little. :)

Comment: @xander you can indeed connect with a remote terminal program (like for example putty) to a Java socket application. But there are **many** other things off e.g. communication between threads is basically not existing. The array list which should store the participants is local to the class `Client` which handles **a single** connection. The Server class should keep track of all the connections it has.

Comment: I noticed you have multiple readers for the same socket, `BufferedReader name = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(verbindung.getInputStream()));` you already have `BufferedReader br` initialized above,w hy don't you use that?

Comment: I just tested your code it works at least as an echo server (you can send text and it responds to you), for multi client connection you need to store an InputStream and OutputStream for every client and the server need to send the message to **all** clients, not only the sender. That's the basic idea I let you figure out how to do that, but @L.Spillner is also right there are some otehr things to fix, too.

Comment: Ok I will try my best. I think I know how to fix it now. Thanks guys